# Your browser security settings don't permit automatic execution of paste operations

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser

I am using a `MaskedEditExtender` within my custom control in an ASP.Net application. Whenever I try to paste some data into the textbox, especially in firefox browser. A popup alert prompts me the following:

> Your browser security settings don't permit the automatic execution of
>   paste operations. Please use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+V instead.

I want to avoid this popup alert. Please provide your suggestions.

Thanks in advance,
Santhosh

Comment: How you are pasting? using shortcut key / using Popup menu?

Comment: i want to use ctrl+v to paste into the textbox. once i do that , the popup comes, so i am forced to paste in the popup alert box. I want to paste directly in the textbox rather.

Comment: Show your Client Code / javascript / Actual server control code, so that i can help you...

Comment: i am using a masked editor extender, it is from ajax control toolkit. it has a property called   [DefaultValue("Your browser security settings don't permit the automatic execution of paste operations. Please use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+V instead.")]
        [ExtenderControlProperty]
        public string ClipboardText { get; set; }